# How do I fetch Campaign Monitor webhook payload with PHP?

Tags: php, api, webhooks

I'm using PHP to create a system that will fetch webhook payload when someone is unsubscribing newsletters, but I can figure out how to fetch the actual payload information in PHP.

Is there any POST data to fetch? How does PHP look for this POST data?

UPDATE: I may be on to something. Seems like the function `http_get_request_body()` will do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http_get_request_body` solves it :)

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue and used the following PHP code for handling Campaign Monitor [Web Hooks](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/api/webhooks/):

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode( $json, TRUE ); //convert JSON into array

foreach ($data['Events'] as $event)
{
    // Process each entry in the request
}
```

The JSON data, once converted to an array will give you data in this format:

```
array (
    'ListID' => 'LIST_ID_KEY',
    'Events' => array (
        0 =>
            array (
                'Type' => 'Subscribe',
                'Date' => '2014-01-01 16:00:00',
                'EmailAddress' => 'test@example.com',
                'Name' => 'John Smith',
                'CustomFields' => array (),
                'SignupIPAddress' => 'API',
            ),
        ),
)
```